# Swift How can i convert view to landscape , inside portrait device orientation? It is possible?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

How can i convert view to landscape inside portrait device orientation

My View controller Code.

```
import UIKit

class SampleViewController: UIViewController {


    var commingtextview:String = ""


    @IBOutlet weak var textview: UITextView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColorFromRGBs(0x000000)
        navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor();


       textview.text = self.commingtextview

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

`Important !` **My project portrait must be portrait i want to change only this view orientation to landscape.**

Also my project orientation

[x] Portrait

[ ] Upside Down

[ ] Landscape Left

[ ] Landscape Right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :-

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
  // Set whatever frame you want
  // self.view.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin,yOrigin,Width,Height)


}
```

Comment: no i didnt change it to landscape left or right my project must be portrait

Comment: Yeah only when this view opened will be rotate 90 degrees

Comment: i did   self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,screenSize.width,screenSize.height) but same my view looking half !

Comment: need to resolve view half error after i will approve your answer.

Comment: whats `screenSize`?

Comment: iphone full screen Scale to fill

Comment: i approved your answer thank you also if you resolve half size view i will more hapoy Thanks !